# Save an entire JFrame in a database

Tags: database, swing, jframe, jython, jython-2.7

I have created a relatively large Jython JFrame, full of fields, tabs, tables and nested tables.
I honestly wouldn't want to take all these fields and create a super giant relational database, far from it. 
I would just like to take the whole frame and save it, without taking field by field (I would never end up otherwise ...!).
I know this is not best practice, but I would highly prefer to do so, even thinking about future purposes.
Not being a backend expert, I was wondering which database technology (DBMS and similar) lends itself to being able to save a JFrame, therefore an object / class.
The goal, once the JFrame has been saved, is to recall it, with the related database query language you would suggest, and to reopen it and see all the fields filled in as I left them, nested elements included.
I sincerely hope that there is a way to be able to save a JFrame in a DB and extract it exactly as it was left.
This would give an important implication to my future projects.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the best you can do is to serialize it (to db or to a file, does not matter). And of course, this sound as a very bad design. I mean the tables show a dataset, right? Save the dataset into the database, not the table. The same with fields and the rest.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Thanks so much for the tip. Unfortunately I will have to proceed in the direction of serialization, and I believe that as DMBS I will use MySql. A curiosity... the type of data to be set on the column will therefore be `BIT`?